# Convergence of Newton Iteration

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

For $a>0$, I want to compute $\frac{1}{a}$ using Newton's iteration by finding a zero of $f(x)=a-\frac{1}{x}$. Newton's iteration formula reads $$x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}=2x_k-ax_k^2$$

By the Banach Fixed Point Theorem, I can conclude that this Netwon iteration converges for starting values in the interval $I=\left(\frac{1}{2a}, \frac{3}{2a}\right)$.

Now I would like to show that we also have convergence for starting values in $\left(0,\frac{1}{a}\right]$.

To this end, it would be enough to show that at some point of the iteration, we land in the interval $I$, right? Is that the right approach? How can we show that?

Comment: If $x_0 \in (0,1/a)$ then try to show that $x_n$ is increasing and bounded above by $a$. Convergence is then guaranteed by the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_sequence_of_real_numbers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a$ is an unessential parameter. Indeed
$$x_{k+1}=2x_k-ax_k^2$$
is equivalent to 
$$ax_{k+1}=2ax_k-a^2x_k^2$$
i.e. by setting $t=ax$,
$$t_{k+1}=2t_k-t_k^2.$$

---

Then notice that the function $f(t)=2t-t^2$ maps $[0,2]$ to $[0,1]$, and values outside this range to negative.

As

$$0<t<1\implies t<f(t)<1$$
and
$$f(0)=0,f(1)=1$$
and
$$t<0\implies f(t)<t,$$
we have convergence to $x=\frac1a$ for $x_0$ in $(0,\frac2a)$, convergence to $x=0$ for $x_0=0\lor x_0=\frac2a$ and divergence elsewhere.

---

**Extra**:

The convergence speed can be assessed from

$$1-t_{k+1}=1-2t_k+t_k^2=(1-t_k)^2.$$

Then by induction,

$$1-t_n=(1-t_0)^{2^n}.$$

Again, this converges when $|1-t_0|\le1$, and does it quadratically.

---

The iterates, converging to a square function

[image]

Comment: May I ask what you used to do this plot? I love that grid, especially that it has $x$ and $y$ coordinates on both sides of the graph.

Comment: @Variable: this is the free Microsoft Mathematics, an excellent product. Unfortunately, it has the bad habit of choosing unwanted values for the ticks and numerical labels.

Answer (score 0):

The Banach fixed point theorem isn't always the best for proving convergence. Your function is convex for $x>0$ and concave for $x<0$. You might be able to use this. Try doing [this exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zm0A.jpg) (Spivak's calculus book) for a better idea of what I am suggesting.